# assignment form incompatible pointer type

Tags: c, pointers, structure

I am getting a warning saying assignment from incompatible pointer type .
I am new to programming and tried my best but still couldn't figure it out.
I am getting the following error:
20  6   D:\DS programs\practical 2\employees_structure_pointer.c    [Warning] assignment from incompatible pointer type

```
/* Accept n employee details using structure and pointer and display their details. */

#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

struct employee
{
    int no,salary;
    char name[10],desig[10];
}*ptr;

int main()
{
    int i,n;
    printf("Enter total number of employees: ");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    
    ptr = (int*)calloc(n,sizeof(struct employee));
    printf("\nEnter employee details: \n");
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        printf("Enter employee number: ");
        scanf("%d",&(ptr+i)->no);
        printf("Enter name of the employee: ");
        scanf("%s",(ptr+i)->name);
        printf("Enter designation of the employee: ");
        scanf("%s",(ptr+i)->desig);
        printf("Enter salary of the employee: ");
        scanf("%d",&(ptr+i)->salary);
        printf("\n");
    }
    
    printf("Employee details are: \n");
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        printf("\nEmployee number is: %d",(ptr+i)->no);
        printf("\nEmployee name is: %s",(ptr+i)->name);
        printf("\nEmployee designation is: %s",(ptr+i)->desig);
        printf("\nEmployee salary is: %d",(ptr+i)->salary);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `ptr` is a pointer to a `struct employee`, but you explicitly cast the return value of `malloc` to `(int *)`, which is a pointer type incompatible to `(struct employee *)`. You don't need the cast here; `malloc` returns a `void *`, which is a compatible assignment. So: `ptr = malloc(...);`

Comment: @MOehm Please make this an answer, it is perfect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You define `ptr` as  a poiner to a `struct employee`:

```
struct employee
{
    int no,salary;
    char name[10],desig[10];
}*ptr;
```

Then you allocate memory to hold a dynamic array of `n` such structs:

```
ptr = (int*)calloc(n,sizeof(struct employee));
```

The functions `calloc` and `malloc` return a pointer to void, `void *`. You cast that pointer explicitly to a pointer to `int`. The right-hand side of this assignment now has type `int *`.

The left-hand side expects a `struct employee *`. There lies your pointer incompatibility.

There is a reason why `c`/`malloc` returns a `void *`: In C, a pointer to void can be assigned to any pointer type without cast. So you don't need the cast. Your memory allocation should be just:

```
ptr = calloc(n, sizeof(struct employee));
```

or perhaps

```
ptr = calloc(n, sizeof(*ptr));
```

On the other hand, C++ requires an explicit cast, so some people do cast anyway to be compatible to C++ compilers. If you do that, you must cast to the correct pointer type. (The explicit cast makes `malloc` quite verbose in C++, but you will usually use `new` instead anyway.)